# Getting Google Map to fill main container that contains content

Tags: css, google-maps, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a solution with Bootstrap 3. I have a header and footer with a full-width container in between. In this full width container I need to embed a Google Map full height of the browser but above the map is some content e.g a heading or a toggle switch.

[Edit] The header and footer are fixed height and fixed to the top and bottom of the browser. The middle part of the browser I wish to fill the remaining space.

I have found this solution which fills the page nicely but I can't get a heading above the map.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27301088/285457

Thanks in advance.

```js
$(function() {
  var mapDiv = document.getElementById("map_canvas");
  /// Set control options for map
  var zoptions = {
    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT,
    style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
  };
  /// Position of map using coord that were passed else do nothing.
  var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(40.716948, -74.003563);
  /// Set basic map options using above control options
  var options = {
    zoom: 10,
    zoomControlOptions: zoptions,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
    center: pos
  };
  this.map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, options);
})
```

```css
html,body,.container-fluid,#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
}

.container-fluid {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#map_header {
  height:50px;
}

#map_canvas {
  border-top: 50px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 20px solid #fff;
  bottom:50px;
}

header {
  height: 50px;
}

footer {
  height: 20px;
}

#map-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 50px;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<header class="hidden-print">
  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">menus etcs</div>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="container-fluid" id="map-container">
  <div id="map_header">This is part of the map content</div>
  <div id="map_canvas" class="map_canvas"></div>
</div>
<footer class="navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
  <div class="row">footer stuff</div>
</footer>
```

Here's the fiddle > https://jsfiddle.net/johnny5a/vnr03ufs/6/

Comment: You need `menus etcs` on Map just like` MAP` and `Satellite` tab right?

Comment: we need more clarity of what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: @MiletaDulovic - the header and footer are fixed. the map-container is fluid part. So when you increase the size of the browser - the header and footer stay fixed to top and bottom but the map-container increases and decreases in size to fill the middle.

Comment: Currently, it is working like that on a Fiddle that you provided. Do you want map to go under header and footer?

Comment: Oh, wait. You want the whole map to scale with a screen? You want the whole map to be visible at all times? You want it to scale its width and height?

Comment: @MiletaDulovic - in my fiddle, the "streetview man" and the Google copyright is cut off. And also the text "This is part of the map content" is under the header. In answer to your question, I would like the "map-container" to not go under the header or the footer. And yes I would like to scale width and height. Really sorry with my explanation

Answer (score 0):

Based on the info I got from comments here is a solution

When you put position fixed on the map it is removed from the flow of the document and it won't be attached to anything but the browser itself. You need to modify your CSS a bit

```css
body {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Also your `container-fluid` needs this CSS

```css
.container-fluid{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

This should fix the problem.

You can read about positioning [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)